# How can I exclude a button and a label from form serialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization

I want to use form serialization but exclude a button and a label from the serialization.

This is a version of the javascript I have:

```
var saveBtn = document.getElementById("btnSaveButton");
var saveLbl = document.getElementById("lblSaveLabel");
var originalFormData = $("#MasterForm").not(saveBtn, saveLbl).serialize();
$("form :input").on('change keyup paste mouseup', function () {
    var newFormData = $("#MasterForm").serialize();
    if (originalFormData != newFormData) {
        //some code
    } else {
        //some other code
    }
});
```

See:  .not(saveBtn, saveLbl)

That is not excluding the button or the label.

Can someone please help me and let me know how I can exclude the button and the label from the serialization?

What essentially happens is I switch the display from the button to the label and back depending on whether the user has made any change to the form.

UPDATE UPDATE

Thank you for the responses ... appears something is amiss ...

There might be too much html to post here ...

Using vb.net. I have a master page, within it is a page called Admin.aspx, and within that is a usercontrol called Bundles.ascx.

In the code of Bundles.ascx I have this javascript:

```
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(prmRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(prmRequest);
    function prmRequest(sender, args) {
       setupFormChangeCheck("btnSaveBundle", langId); 
   }
```

In a master javascript file I have the function setupFormChangeCheck, which looks like this:

```
function setupFormChangeCheck(txtName, langId) {
    try {
        savebtnFnctn('dis', txtName, langId)
        var originalFormData = $("#MasterForm").serialize();
        $("form :input").on('change keyup paste mouseup', function () {
            var newFormData = $("#MasterForm").serialize();
            if (originalFormData != newFormData) {
                savebtnFnctn('en', txtName, langId)
            } else {
                savebtnFnctn('dis', txtName, langId)
            }
        });
    } catch (err) { }
}
```

On the same master javascript file I have the function savebtnFunction, which looks like this:

```
function savebtnFnctn(event, txtName, langId) {
    var saveBtn = document.getElementById(txtName);
    var saveLbl = document.getElementById(txtName.replace("btn", "lbl"));
    if (event == 'en') {
        saveBtn.style.display = "inline";
        saveLbl.style.display = "none";
    } else if (event == 'dis') {
        saveBtn.style.display = "none";
        saveLbl.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

The user control is loaded dynamically, because the same page has multiple use controls and unless I load the one control dynamically, all load ... slows things down incredibly.

Loading a user control dynamically leads to serious postback challenges. So, the vast majority of the user control interactions are handled client side with jquery. For Bundle.ascx this is done in Bundle.js

SOOOOO ....

When the user control is loaded, setupFormChangeCheck fires, which runs the 'dis' (disable) event in function savebtnFnctn.

Here is the problem I noticed today as I tried the code from suggestions above.

When I interact in the Bundle uc, setupFormChangeCheck does not fire from the beginning. What first fires is this line $("form :input").on('change keyup paste mouseup', function ()

And no matter what I do, click in a textbox even without changing anything, leads this:  originalFormData != newFormData to be true and the Save button remains enabled ...

I should add that all the controls in the Bundle user control are inside an updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

Long explanation I know, sorry ... if anyone has any idea to solve this, I would be eternally grateful.

Thank you.  Erik

Comment: can you show us your HTML code for form?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery's .not() method takes selector, not elements.
Also, you are matching the form itself, not the inputs of it.

Since you do know the IDs of the elements to exclude, use this instead:

```
var data = $("#MasterForm").find("input, textarea, select").not("#btnSaveButton, #lblSaveLabel").serialize();
```

1. You select the form.
2. Then you select the form elements underneath.
3. Then you exclude the concrete elements from the collection.
4. Lastly you serialize the results.

NOTE: You should use strict comparison `!==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Also, if you use **<label>** and **<button>** tags then `$("#MasterForm").find("input, textarea, select").serialize()` should be enough to get only input data.